# Excel-VBA: Ignore hidden rows in a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I was searching for my problem .. but i couldn't find something good.

Im trying to copy some values from sheet 1 to sheet 2.. 
In sheet 1("xy") there are no hidden rows. In sheet 2("Adress") there are.

I would use a for-loop to do that:

```
end = cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlUp).row
Row = 1
For i = 11 To end
    Sheets("xy").Select
    Cells(Row, 19).Copy
    Sheets("Adress").Select
    Cells(i, 19).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Row = Row + 1
Next i
```

The problem is that the loop is still using the hidden rows in sheet2("Adress") ... 
How can I skip them ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `end` is a reserved keyword in VBA

Comment: Oh okay.. i just used "end" to show you the code .. in real i use the german word :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to paste it over separately using multiple paste commands as opposed to all at once as you could skip the hidden rows manually. The following code should work for doing it automatically:

```
end = cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlUp).row
Row = 1
For i = 11 To end
  If Not Worksheet("Adress").Cells(i, 19).hidden Then  
    Worksheet("Adress").Cells(i, 19) = Worksheet("xy").Cells(Row, 19)
    Row = Row + 1
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that would be too much work .. there is too much data in the sheet :/ I really wanna use a loop for that

Comment: Ahh, so there is more than just a few hidden rows, I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks so much :). I had to change "Worksheet("...")" into "sheets("...")" and .cells(i,19).hidden into .rows(i).hidden.